# Expand width of TextView, TableRow, and TableView

Tags: android, dynamic, tableview

I'm trying to dynamically add tables, rows, images, and textviews to a view depending upon the content of a text file on a server.  All is going well save for the fact that the text is only filling up half the page.

Here's my code:

```
private void setMainView(String section, String selection){
    mTableView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    mTableView.removeAllViews();
    ArrayList<String> info = getInfoArray(section, selection);
    String[] instructions = info.get(0).split("\\|"); 
    String[] values = info.get(1).split("\\|");
    for(int i=1; i < instructions.length; i++){
        if (instructions[i].equals("@image")){
            TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);

            ImageView newImage = new ImageView(this);
            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) newImage.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = 120;
            params.height = 120;
            // existing height is ok as is, no need to edit it
            newImage.setLayoutParams(params);
            newRow.addView(newImage);
             mTableView.addView(newRow);
        }else{
            TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
            TextView newText = new TextView(this);
            newText.setText(instructions[i] + ": " + values[i]);
            newText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            newRow.addView(newText);
            mTableView.addView(newRow);
        }

    }
    TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
    newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
    TextView newText = new TextView(this); 
    newText.setText(info.get(2));
    newText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    newText.setSingleLine(false);

    newText.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    newText.setMaxLines(100);
    newRow.addView(newText);
    mTableView.setPadding(70, 20, 70, 0);
    mTableView.addView(newRow);
}
```

Here's my xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</TableLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here's what I get:

[image: From the simulator]

What I want it to do is to fill the screen almost to end with the latin filler text instead of it only filling up half the screen. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What's the layout for your tableLayout1?

Comment: @Uxonith I updated my question with the xml for tableview1. I hope that helps.

Comment: Have you tried changing wrap_content to match_parent in your xml?

Comment: I don't know if you've found the answer yet, but you still didn't display the contents of your tableLayout1 xml.  I was actually wondering if there might be two columns in your xml layout and that would explain why your latin filler text is only taking up half of the screen width.  Maybe try setting a background color on your table to make sure it is taking up the width you expect and then you know if it's the TableRow or the TableLayout causing the problem?

Comment: @Uxonith You are right, I did have two columns in there. I removed everything though, and updated the xml above to include the entire xml file. Still no change.

Comment: I can't tell what String would be in each row.

Comment: @RickFalck It's pulling it from a text file. Even if I included the code you wouldn't be able to tell. Essentially, the latin text should be in one large textview, and the two lines above it each have their own textview.

Comment: @Uxonith Had to re-apply xml changes. Should be viewable now.

Comment: @Uxonith I also changed the background color as you suggested. The entire screen is now blue (save for the drawer and the text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your bug:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />   <------------ HERE!!!!!
```

You want the following textview to be INSIDE of the FrameLayout!  Like this:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Try this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

You will add the TextViews to scroll_layout.

Comment: When I do that I get an error for xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" Unexpected name prefix "xmlns" found for tag TableLayout"

Comment: When I remove that line (leaving <TableLayout) the tableview is gone completely.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the FrameLayout, and only have the TableLayout.  The DrawerLayout requires a ViewGroup type.  It doesn't have to be a FrameLayout.  But, there can only be ONE other parent ViewGroup in it other than the ListView.  Putting the TV inside the FL should be OK.

Comment: Well, that's progress. The table is back now, and everything is looking good except for the row with the latin filler being entirely black for some reason.

Comment: Why not use a ScrollView (inside the FrameLayout) and just add the TextViews to the ScrollView?

Comment: When I try to add anything to the ScrollView the app crashes.

Comment: You add to the linearlayout within the scrollview

Comment: Okay, I switched it to Linear Layout and now it works, except there is still a solid black block underneath.

Comment: I edited my answer.  Setting the layout_height to WRAP_CONTENT is important for everything but the parent FrameLayout.

Comment: Save for a giant black box underneath the latin text, your code works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this....

```
 TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
```

Comment: Where would I put that exactly? Looks like there's more I'd have to put in there, or at least change TableLayout to reference something specific.

Comment: in place of this  newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to have an effect.